# ACF Content Not Showing

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created ACF Fields for Wordpress User page Text and image When I try to display on single.php its not showing nither image or text is showing below is screenshot for refrence.

https://prnt.sc/ezFU-JPZH3Rs

```html
 <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <div class="home-blog-author">
                                            <?php
                                             $avatar_image= get_field('user_image', 'user_'. $author_id );
                                            ?>
                                            <picture>
                                                <img src="<?php echo $avatar_image['url']; ?>" class="img-fluid" alt="<?php echo $avatar_image['alt']; ?>">
                                            </picture>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-8 align-self-center ps-0">
                                        <div class="home-author-name">
                                            <h5><?php //echo the_field('user_name', 'user_' .$author_id); ?></h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                                <span><?php echo get_the_date('d/m/Y'); ?></span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: How are you setting `$author_id`, and have you inspected the value to make sure it maps to an author with data?

Comment: $author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');

Comment: And, have you inspected that value to make sure it is the author you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that in your snippet you have the name text commented out, right? Otherwise you have multiple possible failure points. Off the top of my head:

1. Are you sure you're retuning the html as expected (with or without the ACF data)? If not, then you may have the wrong template or other problems. If so:
2. Are you sure you have the ACF `user_image` field set to return an array - and in particular for the user you're testing?
3. Have you tried returning the ACF field by key rather than field name? That sometimes helps.

Comment: I am showing in single.php I tried everything none of them worked

Comment: Why did you mark my answer is correct if it hasn't solved your issue? You might want to add screenshots of your field as set in ACF and as present and filled in on in your user-edit page. While you're at it you might want to include an expanded version of your code including the point where you get $author_id. Assuming you don't have another way to show or log values, you might try echoing $author_id and dumping the field array to the front end.